# How to show maven artifact version in eclipse Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am using eclipse helios and the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin. I wonder if it is possible to configure the plugin (or eclipse) to show the maven artifact version beside the project folder in the package explorer (I too often have to open the pom.xml to check which version I am currently working on - especially on projects which I open seldom).

Other plugins add information next to the project folder (like e.g ClearCase the view name). Would be nice if this is also possible with eclipse/m2eclipse and the artifact version.

Any idea?

Thanks
  Klaus

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Window>Preferences>General>Appearance>Label Decorations>Maven Version Decorator

Comment: Although the question is old I still did not found it yet. Thanks!

Comment: I came across this question while I was looking for the answer myself.